# "Casting to Locked"

Tags: security, screencast

I purchased a LG Style X over black friday.  Everything is stock and I don't even know if it can be rooted.

I connect it to my apartment's wifi and I get a notification stating "Casting to Locked".  I don't know what locked is.  I don't know who owns it.  Why am I casting to an unknown device and how do I prevent this from happening in the future?